# Vertically misaligned tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image: Tags on tags list with vertical misalignment]

The vertical alignment of the tags is incorrect on Firefox.

```
.post-tag {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Should fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.